# Facebook Graph API : permission for display facebook feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a simple website without connexion system for user, and I want to display my latest facebook feeds on my website

For that, I have to do it with Facebook Graph API and a GET request like that :

https://graph.facebook.com/MyPage/feed?fields=full_picture,picture,link,message,created_time&limit=5&access_token=MyAccessToken

I tried it on postman but I have this error :

```
"error": {
        "message": "(#10) This endpoint requires the 'pages_read_user_content' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature. Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login-permissions#manage-pages and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS for details.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 10,
}
```

I tried to ask theses permissions to Facebook by explaining my use case of theses permissions and they refused, there is the message :

" Although your video capture and notes provide a valid use case, we were unable to verify it when we logged into your app. Please ensure that your app has successfully implemented the requested permission and resubmit it for review so that we can complete testing."

My use case is really simple, they can't check it on their side.

Someone have an idea to how can I get my permission please ? I have to improve my usecase explication, but for me I don't really have a lot of thing to case, My case is really basic and simple

thanks

Comment: You will not get Page Public Content Access approved for this purpose. First of all, this is your _own_ page as you said, so you don't need "public" access permission in the first place; and secondly, the only _allowed_ used case for this feature is to _"Provide competitive benchmark analysis"_.

Comment: What type of access token are you using there, and what permissions does it encompass?

Comment: The _correct_ way to do this, would be to get a page access token, and use that.

Comment: Its is not really my the facebook page , its the page of my town, We made it and I have an admin account, I checked my access token in API Explorer and it's and user token

Comment: If you have admin access to the page, then you should be able to create a page token. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens

Comment: I just did it, and now, my error is : "Please reduce the amount of data you're asking for, then retry your request"  Where can this come from?

Comment: That's a generic response Facebook gives you, when they consider your request too resource-consuming. You can either try and request less fields, or less posts (using a lower `limit` value than the default 25.)

Comment: I tried to reduce my fields, I have only  picture and message, And I have a limit of 5 but still persist, I'm trying it on my dev server and not in prod, Can it be the reason of this error ?

https://graph.facebook.com/Page/feed?fields=picture,message&limit=5&access_token=accesstoken

Comment: No, how would Facebook even know which of your servers was "dev" and "prod" ... I can make this kind of request without any problems in Graph API Explorer, what response do you get there? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Comment: It's work, the issue was from my Url, I modified it and now it's work, thanks you !